# Error while parsing JSON file

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse a file using ***quick-json***  https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/

However, I'm getting below error. Anyone how idea what does it mean?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.json.exceptions.JSONParsingException: @Key-Heirarchy::root/myfile.dxf/0/ B L D G[2]/ @Key::  Illegal character '}' is identified while parsing for VALUE_TOKEN...@Position::222
    at com.json.utils.JSONUtility.handleFailure(JSONUtility.java:124)
```

Update: My code

```
String inputJsonString2 = readfile("output.txt");

    String inputJsonString3 = minify2(inputJsonString2);
    stringToFile( inputJsonString3, "D:\\Development\\land_overlay\\enhanced\\outputmin.txt") ;
    System.out.println(inputJsonString3);


    JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
    JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
     Map jsonData=parser.parseJson(inputJsonString3);

    Map rootJson=(Map)jsonData.get("root");
```

My File snippet, notice since the file is big I'm only showing the begining of the file:

```
{"myfile4.dxf":
   {"0":
      {" B L D G":
         [
          { 
             "min":[613160.120556,2614000.490432,0.000000],
             "max":[613169.049128,2614001.740432,0.000000]
          },
          {
           "min":[614496.220817,2613960.530343,0.000000],
           "max":[614505.149389,2613961.780343,0.000000]
           },}
      ," L A N E":[{"min":[612651.615812,2610886.017265,0.000000],"max":[612655.960193,2610894.745445,0.000000]},{"min":[611584.022485,2611661.664140,0.000000],"max":           [611585.362832,2611670.545469,0.000000]},}," L A N E
```

Comment: Is your json short enough to show us? You are havin problems bear } character, we could ind it.

Comment: Try to validate the JSON first using any JSON validator. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: not sufficient information.can you show the code?

Comment: I've added code and the beginning of the file. I can't validate because i don't have the XML configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are simply missing two curly braces at the end of your JSON.

Comment: I added only the beginning of the file.